# Flutter no es reconocido de alguna manera en mi Mac

Tags: flutter, terminal

tengo instalado flutter en una carpeta como me dice el su web, cuando accedo en la terminal no lo detecta, luego de agregarlo en el BATH de un momento funciona y aparece pero cuando cierro completamente el terminal no aparece los comandos de flutter ni flutter aunque este descargado como tal.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.